# Remove whitespace from PDF Document

Tags: python, removing-whitespace, pdf-extraction, python-camelot

I am using Camelot-py to read and extract attributes from several PDFs. I use table_areas to extract some of the attributes and I am facing difficulties in setting the correct areas, due to the deviation in X or Y co-ordinates between some of the forms. Some forms (Sample 1) have minimum whitespace at the top, while others (Sample 2) have more whitespace. This shifts the y-coordinates by about 10-15

Sample 1
[image]

Sample 2
[image]

Is there a way to crop or uniform them at runtime?

Comment: I have found no direct way to do the same...what I do is either use `tabula.py` or convert pdf to text and then extract text and store it in excel how your table should look like!!

Comment: I do not have the liberty to completely change the approach at this time. I need a way I can use the existing script by cropping off the whitespace at the top

Comment: Upon my research, I have not found any solution to this!! I will follow this question to see if their is any answer to this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is using parameter table_regions, as specified in [Find PDF Dimensions with Camelot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176697/find-pdf-dimensions-with-camelot/54180307#54180307).

Read more about table_regions in: https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#specify-table-regions

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality, you could use [pdfCropMargins](https://github.com/abarker/pdfCropMargins) which crops the margins of PDF files. It is implemented as a command-line application, to call it from Python:

```
import subprocess

filename = "test.pdf"

cmd = f"pdf-crop-margins -v -s -u {filename}"

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split())
proc.wait()
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/abarker/pdfCropMargins#running):

> That command prints verbose output, forces all pages to be the same
>   size (-s) and then crops each page the same amount (-u) for a uniform
>   appearance, retaining the default of 10% of the margins.